# Tkinter Variable Not Updating(Defined outside of function)

Tags: python, tkinter, input

I am working on an input box in tkinter. It is supposed to take a value in(in the entry), and once the "okay" button is pressed, that value will be assigned to a variable. Once the tkinter window is closed, the variable will be printed. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk



root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Input")
root.geometry("400x200")

a = ""

entry1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry1.pack()


def entry1Input():
    a = entry1.get()
    print(a)

okay = tk.Button(root,text = "Okay", command = entry1Input())

okay.pack()



root.mainloop()

print("A: " + a)
```

The problem is that when I close out of the window, the value is the same as when I first defined it. I haven't coded python in a while, so this might be a simple error. Could you please let me know what the mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems.  First, you are not passing the function object here:

```
okay = tk.Button(root,text = "Okay", command = entry1Input())
```

Instead, you are CALLING the function.  The function returns `None`, and that's what you send to `command`.  You need:

```
okay = tk.Button(root,text = "Okay", command = entry1Input)
```

Then, the `a` in your function is local to that function, and goes away when the function ends.  You need:

```
def entry1Input():
    global a
```

I sincerely hope you are not using `a` as your variable name here.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm using a cuz this is just a base model of code for something bigger. Thanks again!